# Date input in form for google calendar api in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, api, date, datepicker

I am currently using the google API where I am creating an event which will be saved in the google calendar. I am having problem in converting the start and end date when submitting the form.  The other elements are working perfectly apart from the start and end date.
I have tried different ways but in vain.Can you figure out what is the problem with it.

Here is the form:
[image]

Here is the code:
[image]

The output is as follows:
[image]

Comment: start and end have 2 property "date" and value inside like start: {date: '2018-12-01'}  and not start: '2018-12-01'. further you need to format the date from mm-dd-yyyy to yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: Its better to provide the code in text form instead of screenshots so people can copy &paste it figure out whats wrong

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

`start = new date ("2018-12-2");`

it has to be (capitial D)

`start = new Date ("2018-12-2");`

But anyway, you overriding your variable after that so you could just drop the line cause it's useless.

Comment: `new Date ("2018-12-2")` may well produce an invalid Date as it's not a format supported by ECMA-262 so parsing is implementation dependent. Even where it is parsed to a valid Date, it might be treated as UTC or local.

Answer (score -1):

change below while assigning value in event.start and event.end

```
 event.start = {"date": start}
 event.end = {"date": end}
```

Comment: A good answer should explain why the OP has their issue and how your code fixes it.

Comment: @RobG yeah, given above in comments